# Data.SE disagrees with SO on Number of Edits

Tags: support, suggested-edits, data-explorer, edits

[This page](https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/99430) on StackOverflow says:

> muntoo had 371 edit suggestions approved, and 36 edit suggestions rejected.

[This query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/1820/number-of-edits?UserId=365102) on Data.SE says:

> Total Edits: 267

Maybe I just suck at SQL (I do; I don't even know what `SELECT` means!), but why do they disagree?

Comment: Data.SE isn't querying the real database, it's using a monthly(?) dump.

Comment: @Jeremy Might as well post that as the answer :)

Comment: @MatthewRead: Thanks, but I didn't want to post as an answer because I didn't know the details. I feel less bad about putting no effort into a comment.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The query makes the assumption that you are the last editor of the post (i.e., `LastEditorUserId` is your user ID) which isn't always guaranteed to be true, because someone could have easily made an edit after you did. This is why the `PostHistory` table exists, since it contains the full revision history for any given post.

Additionally, as [Jeremy Banks points out](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105027/data-se-disagrees-with-so-on-number-of-edits#comment-268884), the data used by the Data Explorer isn't always up-to-date, so even in the case of valid queries the Data Explorer results can occasionally lag behind those of the actual sites. To check when the data was last updated, you can take a look at the [Data Explorer main page](http://data.stackexchange.com) and find the date above for "most recent" in each site listing (image courtesy [Michael Mrozek](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/145982/michael-mrozek)):

[image: example of most recent update location]

This value is also shown in the sidebar of the queries page. In this particular case, the data is relatively fresh, so the variance caused by that shouldn't be too significant.

Comment: So how should I write the query? (This is my first time SQLing, and I haven't read any manuals.)